# Map with no arguments and class method?

Tags: python, functional-programming, dictionary

It seems pretty simple:

```
# builtins work fine:
>>> map (str, [(), (), ()])
['()', '()', '()']

# but no luck for class methods:
>>> class C (object):
...   def m(self):
...     return 42
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> map(c.m, [(), (), ()])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: m() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a parameter to your m method, where the argument of the map will be passed.

```
class C (object):
    def m(self, x):
        return 42

>>> c = C()
>>> map(c.m, [(), (), ()])
[42, 42, 42]
```

See, c.m is a bound method, already like calling m(c), you need a placeholder for the additional parameter passed by map

`c` and the argument passed by map are the 2 arguments to `m` your stack trace is complaining about:

```
TypeError: m() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 4):

`map(f, L)` always calls `f` with a single argument whose values are taken from `L`. It's always a single argument, never zero. The `()`s in the list are not argument lists, they are empty tuples. Outside of a function call, things in parentheses *aren't* arguments to a function, they are objects called "tuples" (think of them as immutable lists). Check the difference between `str()` and `str(())` - `str` with no arguments gives `''` and *not* `'()'`.

If you have tuples of arguments and want to call a callable (function or method) with these arguments, you can use `itertools.starmap`. In particular, if you pass empty tuples the functions will be called with no arguments. It returns an iterator, so if you need a list you need to explicitly use `list()` over the result

```
>>> import itertools
>>> f = lambda: 42
>>> L = [(), (), ()]
>>> values = itertools.starmap(f, L)
>>> print list(values)
[42, 42, 42]
```

In the general case, it works with any tuple of arguments:

```
>>> f = lambda *x: sum(x)
>>> L = [(1,2), (4, ), (5,6)]
>>> values = itertools.starmap(f, L)
>>> print list(values)
[3, 4, 11]
```

If you want to simply call a function multiple times and get the result, you might consider using a list comprehension or a generator expression instead.

```
>>> f = lambda: 42
>>> [f() for _ in xrange(3)]
[42, 42, 42]
>>> values = (f() for _ in xrange(3))
>>> print list(values)
[42, 42, 42]
```

If you have a list of empty tuples like in your example, you might use `xrange(len(L))` in the place of `xrange(3)`.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a class method, it lacks the `classmethod` decorator and `self` should be `cls`. But you don't want a class method here anyway, as class methods are methods which operate on classes (you can pass other objects, of course, but that's not the intended use case - the `@classmethod` would be grossly misleading).

You're looking for the term "unbound method", which you get by refering to a member of the *class*, not to an instance thereof. Use `C.m`. Note of course that the method will be called with `self` as (in your example) a tuple and not an instance of `C`. Normally, such trickery should be restricted to avoid this (e.g. `str.lower` and a bunch of strings is O.K.).

Comment: It is fully legitimate to want to pass a bound method to map. It doesn't have to be a classmethod or an unbound method. Actually, bound methods have many more interesting possibilities. See my reply and Alex's below.

Comment: @Carles: Yes, of course. But as I assume OP is familiar with bound methods, I just mentioned how to use unbound ones (i.e. supply `self` from somewhere else).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your decorator to make it a class method, but you probably want a static method:

static:

```
class C(object):
    @staticmethod
    def m(arg):
        return 42
```

class:

```
class C(object):
    @classmethod
    def m(cls, arg):
        #cls is a reference to the actual "C" type, not an instance of the "C" class.
        return 42
```

Answer (score 1):

First, that's not a class method. A class method takes the class as it's first argument, and is called on the class, not an instance of it:

```
class C(object):
    @classmethod
    def m(cls):
        return 42

map(C.m, range(10))
```

However, that will still break because `map` passes in each item from the iterable to the function, and your method only accepts one argument, the class.

If you change your method to accept the extra argument (`def m(cls, arg)`), it will work. You could also use an instance method instead of a class method:

```
class C(object):
    def m(self, *args): # or def m(self, n)
        return 42
c = C()
map(c.m, range(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

m is a 1-argument method that takes an object of type C.  The syntax "c.m" is actually equivalent to "m(c)", which is just 42.  But 42 is not a function you can map over a list like [(),(),()].

The following should work:

```
class C (object):
    def f(self): return lambda x: x+1

two,three,four = map(C().f(), [1,2,3])
```

Now C().***  returns a function, instead of a constant.

Comment: That doesn't work. `C().f()` would work, but that's another layer of indirection for no good reason... go fix the root of the problem instead.

Comment: Thanks, fixed.  I misinterpreted what the asker wanted.  Sometimes the indirection is useful, for example for returning a function that uses member variables.